# Struct vs Dynamically allocated struct in linked list code C

Tags: c, memory, struct, dynamic-memory-allocation

I have a complete linked list code, that reverses the contents of a string. My problem is trying to understand the meaning of the "&" operator and the "*" operator. And the significance that it has to the code.

Here is the main code;

```
#include "strlst.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
char letter;
char *string = "dlrow olleh\n";
struct strlst_struct *item_ptr, *list_ptr;

list_ptr = NULL;

for (;*string;string++)
{
    item_ptr = new_item( *string );
    push( &list_ptr, item_ptr );
}

while (list_ptr)
{
    item_ptr = pop( &list_ptr );
    letter = free_item( item_ptr );
    printf( "%c", letter );
}
printf( "\n" );

return 0;
}
```

As you can see, list_ptr is called in a function with the "&" operator, meanwhile, item_ptr isn't. I'd like to know why that is the case and what difference it makes.

I will post the functions that are required for the first loop. The first function is easy for me to understand, it seems that we are just setting the character 'd' as the data in item_ptr and then setting the pointer to NULL.

The second function is where I become confused. I have no clue what is going on with the '*' and what it does to the program.

First function:

```
struct strlst_struct *new_item( char character )
{
struct strlst_struct *item_ptr;

item_ptr = malloc( sizeof(struct strlst_struct) );
item_ptr->character = character;
(*item_ptr).next = NULL;

return item_ptr;
}
```

Second Function:

```
void push( struct strlst_struct **list_ptr, 
       struct strlst_struct *item_ptr )
/* Add the item pointed to by item_ptr to the beginning of the list 
   pointed to by list_ptr.
*/
{
item_ptr->next = *list_ptr;
*list_ptr = item_ptr;
}
```

Even if you do not understand the context I provided, just knowing when and why to use the "*" and "&" in dynamically allocated structs is something that I am not understanding.

Ps. The strlst_struct definition is:

```
struct strlst_struct
{
char character;
struct strlst_struct *next;
};
```

Comment: `&` is the "address-of" operator and `*` is the dereference operator. I recommend reading the many C language references and articles about how pointers work.

Answer (score 0):

`void push( struct strlst_struct **list_ptr, 
       struct strlst_struct *item_ptr )`

You can see here that the `item_ptr attribute` is just a simple pointer which holds the address of a regular element of the strlst_struct structure.
On the other hand, the `list_ptr attribute` is a double pointer. This means that it holds the address of a simple or regular pointer which in turn holds the address of a regular variable.

From your declaration:

```
struct strlst_struct *item_ptr, *list_ptr;
```

Neither of the pointers are double pointers (they do not hold the address of another pointer, just a regular element). As you are passing these to the `push()` function here:

```
push( &list_ptr, item_ptr );
```

you must make sure that you are passing a double pointer as your first argument and a normal pointer as your second.
Hence, `&list_ptr` is required : It stores the address of a pointer.

Coming to the operators:
The & operator gives you the address of a variable. Common pointer initialization involves this:

```
int x = 5;
int *ptr_to_x;

ptr_to_x = &x;
```

The * operator is when used in unary operator is the deferencing operator. It allows one to access the value stored at a given address.
Coming back to the above example,
printing the value of `*ptr_to_x` will give you 5, or the value of x. The value stored at the address of x (represented by ptr_to_x) is 5.

Please go through a few tutorials or practise problems to strengthen this very important concept.